# Find the row which has the maximum difference between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with columns `Gold` and `Gold.1`. I want to find the row where the difference of these two columns is the maximum.

For the following DataFrame, this should return me row 6.

```
df
Out: 
   Gold  Gold.1
0     2       1
1     1       4
2     6       9
3     4       4
4     4       8
5     5       5
6     5       2 ---> The difference is maximum (3)
7     5       9
8     5       3
9     5       6
```

I tried using the following:

```
df.where(max(df['Gold']-df['Gold.1']))
```

However that raised a ValueError:

```
df.where(max(df['Gold']-df['Gold.1']))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 1, in 
    df.where(max(df['Gold']-df['Gold.1']))

  File "../python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5195, in where
    raise_on_error)

  File "../python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4936, in _where
    raise ValueError('Array conditional must be same shape as '

ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self
```

How can I find the row that satisfies this condition?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of `.where`, you can use `.idxmax`:

```
(df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1']).idxmax()
Out: 6
```

This will return the index where the difference is maximum.

If you want to find the row with the maximum *absolute* difference, then you can call `.abs()` first.

```
(df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1']).abs().idxmax()
Out: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Though my method is a longer than the above one, people who are comfortable working with lists may find this useful.

```
x= list((df['col1']-df['col2']).abs())
x.index(max(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.Series(df['Gold']-df['Gold.1']).argmax()
```

or using numpy library

```
numpy.argmax(df['Gold']-df['Gold.1'])
```

[argmax() in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html)